# mongodb find in python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have the folowing code:

```
for result in collection.find({}, {"canvas"}):
    print(result)
```

it returns this:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('621fd56893a0600016345993'), 'canvas': {'value1': '-326362238', 'value2': '2087090823'}}
{'_id': ObjectId('6220fa61c084480016455f5d'), 'canvas': {'value1': '838487572', 'value2': '1949564751'}}
```

I need to access the `value1` and `value2` but I cannot figure out how to reach for it ...

Comment: `result['canvas']['value1']` ...?

Comment: {"canvas.value1" , "canvas.value2"}

Comment: How do you access a field's value in a Python dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result['canvas']['value1']` fixes my problem